# How to use preprocessors in objective c

Tags: ios, preprocessor

Hi in one of my applications I have to support that app for IOS6 & IOS7.Inorder to accomplish that first I have to know the current device version. For that I had defined one macro and I am trying to using that macro as a reference to accomplish my task. The code which I wrote is as such below.

In .h file I defined IPhoneOSVersion as 50000.

This code is in .m file

```
if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] isEqualToString:@"7.0"])
    {

      #undef IPhoneOSVersion
      #define IPhoneOSVersion 70000

        NSLog(@"_IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED after is %d",IPhoneOSVersion);
    }
    else 
    {

          #undef IPhoneOSVersion
          #define IPhoneOSVersion 60000

        NSLog(@"_IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED after is %d",IPhoneOSVersion);
    }

NSLog(@"_IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED after is %d",IPhoneOSVersion);
```

And if i run this code in IOS7. In console the data have to print like this _IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED after is 70000 but unfortunately I am getting _IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED after is 60000. Even I put a break points at else condition also but that is not executing but the macro value is changing.Can anyone please let me know why the macro value changing like this.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be hardcoding against the OS version, Apple recommended way of supporting multiple OS versions is to check for some specific class, API, protocol or function, this allows for greater flexibility as some of that stuff is sometimes backwards compatible.

Here's a pretty decent tutorial on how to check for existence of specific resources in code http://www.raywenderlich.com/42591/supporting-multiple-ios-versions-and-devices and the docs from Apple https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/developertools/conceptual/cross_development/Using/using.html

EDIT: To answer your question on why the macro is changed, the compiler goes over both branches of the if-else, thus the last declaration of the macro is used. You can't use a macro like that and change it during runtime, macros are meant to be define before compilation.

Comment: Hi Henri thanks for your response.Can you please let me know is there any other concept of objective c which will help me to achieve my requirement.

Comment: What is your requirement? You have not explicitly stated what you want to do with the OS version during runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You use the preprocessor in Objective-C in exactly the same way as in C or C++. The preprocessor doesn't care about your if/else statements. It sees a sequence of #undef, #define, #undef, #define and performs them one after the other, so in your last line, the last #define is in effect. You cannot influence these #defines with anything happening at runtime.

There are always three OS versions in play: The deployment target (that is the lowest OS version where you allow your app to run), the SDK version, and the actual version at runtime. The first two you set in Xcode; the actual version is obviously out of your control except that you know it is the same or higher than the deployment target.

__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED = Deployment target
__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED = SDK version

Answer (score -1):

Try with

```
if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] == 7.0)
```